# "Set as wallpaper" intent not working with many apps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

In my app, I download an image from the web and I save it as a jpeg. I want to be able to launch an intent so that the image can be set as a phone wallpaper. The following code works with Google Photo app but not with QuickPic or Nova Launcher, which say errors like "can't open image".

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(mFilePath );
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "uri is: " + uri);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
```

The URI is always as follows:

```
/storage/emulated/0/wallpapers/FILENAME.jpg
```

and the picture gets always correctly saved to the gallery.